# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'ObjC' cannot compile my app anymore

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

[image]

I literally did everything to solve the problem.
But nothing helps. I hope you can help me out.
What specific must I do to resolve the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Look in your Project Settings for "Other Linker Flags" ...

It looks like you have `ObjC` there, when what you want is `-ObjC`

If it's not there, do a search in your project for the string `ObjC` - it should show up somewhere that it shouldn't be.